Why is my GE washing machine control panel randomly beeping?
We have the GE GTW490ACJ5WS washing machine and the control panel is just beeping randomly. Even if we haven't washed anything. There are no lights on either. Can somebody suggest a part that needs replaced?
Here is a video

My dishwasher started doing that because a button was sticking. I don't see any similar buttons in your panel, but fiddle with all the controls to see if you can affect the behavior.

Still works OK?

Yes, it is seemingly still doing its job
